# SPOJ solution of GRAVITY

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

I am solving problem [GRAVITY](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GRAVITY/) on SPOJ. Each test case is a rectangular ASCII grid of dimensions `m` × `n`, and you have to determine whether it is possible to find a path from the `'S'` square to the `'T'` square, moving using the space squares and avoiding `'#'` obstacles, in at most `O` steps (diagonal steps allowed).

I am using normal BFS but I am getting TLE. The time limit is 2 sec and my code should easily run within this limit.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
typedef pair <int , int > pii;

#define INF (1000000000)
#define ull unsigned long long
#define s(n) scanf("%d",&n)
#define s2(a,b) scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)
#define s3(a,b,c) scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c)

int O,m,n;
int dr[]={0,0,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1}; //right,left,up,down,down-right,down-left,up-right,up-left
int dc[]={1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1,-1};
int inRange(int a,int b){ if(a>=0 && a<m && b>=0 && b<n) return 1;return 0;}


char arr[101][101];map <pii,int > dist;


int bfs(int a,int b)
{
    queue <pii> q;    
    dist[pii(a,b)]=0;
    q.push(pii(a,b));
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        pii front=q.front();q.pop();
        a=front.first;b=front.second;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            int x=a+dr[i],y=b+dc[i];

            if(inRange(x,y) && arr[x][y]!='#' && dist[pii(x,y)]==INF)
            {
                dist[pii(x,y)]=dist[pii(a,b)]+1;
                q.push(pii(x,y));
            }
            if(inRange(x,y) && arr[x][y]=='T')
            {
                dist[pii(x,y)]=dist[pii(a,b)]+1;
                return dist[pii(x,y)];
            }            
        }
    }
    return INF;
}


int main()
{
    int t;
    s(t);    
    while(t--)
    {        

        int Sx=-1,Sy=-1,Tx=-1,Ty=-1;
        s3(O,m,n);
        char ch;
        scanf("%c",&ch);    //for end of line character

        dist.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                scanf("%c",&ch);
                arr[i][j]=ch;
                dist[pii(i,j)]=INF;
                if(arr[i][j]=='S')
                    Sx=i,Sy=j;
                if(arr[i][j]=='T')
                    Tx=i,Ty=j;
            }
            scanf("%c",&ch);   //for end of line character 
        }


        if(Sx==-1 || Sy==-1 || Tx==-1 || Ty==-1)
        {
            printf("Impossible\n");
            continue;
        }
        int val=bfs(Sx,Sy);
        if(val <= O)
            printf("Possible\n");
        else
             printf("Impossible\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You should pass `O` to your `bsf` and terminate it, once you reach zero oxigen. Big map with low `O` can cause TLE.
2. You don't need the `map`, you can reuse the array and just mark visited spots (e.g. with '*'). This would be ***wave*** algorithm (handle all nodes in the queue at the start of the step, reduce counter `O` and proceed to next step, unless `T` or zero `O` reached). This is simplification of Dijkstra algorithm for graph with all weights=1.
3. Your code is hard to read. You are on Code Review! You are using C++ but program like in old C. Use `typedef` instead of `#define` when possible, avoid super-shortcuts like `s` and `s2`, please.

Answer (score 5):

This `#define` here:

> ```
> #define ull unsigned long long
> ```

Should be changed to a `typedef` instead, like this:

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;
```

This line here:

> ```
> #define ll long long
> ```

Should also be changed to this:

```
typedef long long ll;
```

In general, if you're using `#define` to shorten type names, you should be using `typedef` instead.

---

You should also drop this line here:

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

There are many things that can happen if you have this line, especially if you're working on a large project, and none of them are good. See [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more details.

There's also a reason it's named `std` and not `standard`. The prefix `std` is shorter.

---

Your `inRange` function should `return` a `bool`, like this:

```
bool inRange(int x, int y) 
{
    return x >= 0 && a < m && y >= 0 && y < n;
}
```

This eliminates the need for the `if` statements.

---

Instead of defining your own custom infinity (`INF`), you should be using [`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity).

---

Finally, you don't need to `return 0;` in `main`. `main` is a special function, so the compiler will automatically insert `return 0;` if it isn't there.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot review the content of your code because it is very, very unreadable, but I just wanted to point a few things out.

---

According to the signature, `bfs` is supposed to return an `int`.

However, run of the return cases is `INF`, which is merely a constant assigned to `(1000000000)`; that's not necessarily an `int`.

Therefore, when creating the constant `INF`, you should use `const` and a type. This will ensure that `INF` is actually and `int`.

```
const int INF = 1000000000;
```

---

You variable names are very poor. Here are just a few:

```
int O,m,n;
```

Your variable names should describe what the variable is used for and/or what it means; this allows anyone reading your code (that includes you if you were to step away from the code for a while).

Having short, one-letter names or cryptic acronyms does only hurts your code. I wanted to review more of your code, but I could not understand a thing because your variable names said nothing.

---

While I agree with EthanBierlein's points about the `#define` vs `typedef`, there is something that I believe he missed: you don't use `ull` nor do you use `ll` at all in your code.

I did a little <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>ing through your code and not a single `ull` or `ll` turned up.

You can just get rid of these.

---

There are many things to be said about your style, so I'm just going to brush through them very quickly.

- Spacing. Your lines are very cramped, like here:

  ```
  if(arr[i][j]=='T')
  ```

Add some spaces in here, like around the `==`

- You should **always** use braces in your `if` statements and loops. If you one day didn't notice these for even a second and then you added something to your code around, you could be in for a tough debugging session.